# ISO 8601 datetime format: parse 11:05:14 PM into 23:05:14

Tags: python, csv, datetime, iso8601

I currently am getting an ISO format, but I'm not sure how to get the ISO (8601) format.

When I convert the following date 08/10/2015 11:05:14 PM to ISO format, I get 2015-08-10T11:05:14+0000

I should ideally get 2015-08-10T23:05:14+0000

Line which edits the date to iso format is:

```
new[3] = datetime.strptime(new[3], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").isoformat() + '+0000'
```

Code:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import move
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
from pathlib import Path


def change_file(in_file, cols):
    with open(in_file) as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        wr = csv.writer(tmp)
        count = 0
        for row in r:
            if count == 0:
                new = []
                for x in itemgetter(*cols)(row):
                    new.append(x.lstrip())
                wr.writerow(new)
                count += 1
                continue
            if row != '\n':
                new = []
                print(row)

                for x in itemgetter(*cols)(row):
                    new.append(x.lstrip())
                new[3] = datetime.strptime(new[3], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").isoformat() + '+0000'
                print(new)
                wr.writerow(new)
        move(tmp.name, in_file)

for fle in Path('./BM').glob('**/*/cplt.csv'):
    print(fle)
    change_file(str(fle), (6, 2, 1, 0, 5))
```

Comment: Your pattern is `%H:%M:%S %p`, with `%H` you do not need `%p`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - I think the %p addresses the AM/PM part of the datetime right?

Comment: Yes, but [`%H` represents](https://devdocs.io/python2/library/time#time.strftime) 24-hour clock. AM/PM is redundant with that format.

Comment: Reading your question in detail, try using `%I` instead of `%H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly is the input format?

When I change your format string to `%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S`, the following

```
print datetime.strptime('08/10/15 23:05:14', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S').isoformat() + '+0000'
```

gives the correct result:

```
2015-08-10T23:05:14+0000
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the additional info, it should work if you just replace the `%H` with `%I`:

```
 print datetime.strptime('8/10/2015 11:05:14 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').isoformat() + '+0000'
```

From the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> `%I` - Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

Only with `%I` the am/pm part is taken into account.

Comment: My input format is as follow: ['3/11/2016 5:48:49 PM', ' 80008761', ' 246', ' 0.700481055630595', ' 1582422.09999997', ' 1582422.09999997', ' 9998']
The first field.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `%I` format to parse the hour when you use the `%p` directive.

From the docs:

> When used with the strptime() method, the %p directive only affects the output hour field if the %I directive is used to parse the hour.